# XML schema to restrict the range (min, max) of a hexadecimal value

Tags: xml, xsd

I would like to restrict the range of a hexadecimal memory address value in an XML document using a schema. The xml hexadecimal entry has to be in string format as it is parsed from a GUI textbox and directly saved to the XML document after it is validated with the schema document.

I have this.

#### XSD:

```
<xs:simpleType name="memory_address_type">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="([0-9A-Fa-f])+"/>
    <xs:maxLength value="8"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="memory_address"
    type="x:memory_address_type"
    x:use="required"
    x:default="00000000">
```

#### XML:

```
<memory_address>4FFF</memory_address>
```

How should I write the XSD in order to restrict the XML entry to only have a range (minimum and maximum) from 40000 to 47FFF or from 0000 to FFFF?

Answer (score 2):

You're almost done, change your `<xs:simpleType>` declaration like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="memory_address_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:hexBinary">
        <xs:pattern value="4[0-9A-F]{3}"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

and it will do the job.

Comment: The general problem of defining an arbitrary numeric range (e.g. 0x20 to 0x3FF) using regular expressions is of course much harder, but I seem to recall reading that it's always possible.

Comment: Yes indeed. Here the problem is somewhat simple, but it is not the general case.

Comment: I was looking for a more generic solution to cover, as Michael said, arbitary numeric ranges. I may need to rephrase my initial question.

Comment: Wouldn't you want that pattern to read:
<xs:pattern value="[0-4][0-9A-F]{3}"></xs:pattern> ?
Right now this assumes, that the first digit is always '4', i.e. you only cover the range [4000-4FFF]. I assume you would want to allow [0000-4FFF] here.

Answer (score 0):

In XML, the only numeric datatype for hexadecimal numbers is xsd:hexBinary, however, this allows two hexadecimal digits only (to represent a sequence of octets). Therefore, the only way to describe arbitrary hexadecimal values is to use the xsd:string datatype with pattern restrictions, as seen in the question, but strings cannot have numerical ranges for permissible values, only numbers can.

Of course, you can define the permissible characters one by one, and whenever possible, in groups (depending on the range), e.g., 4[A-F0-9]{4} or 40-7. However, defining regex string patterns for hexadecimal digits is not only tedious, but it loses the semantics of the corresponding numbers.